# How to find string in Redis

Tags: redis

I have the following in the json of a redis key:

```
{
"city": "Chennuk",
"state": "TN",
"zipCode": "600125"
}
```

If I know the value (`600125`) of the `zipCode`, then how can I find (search on that value), and get the name/value of the key?

Comment: Well you can always go through all the values until you find what you need. That's what you always need to do when you have a dictionary-like structure. Key searches are fast, value searches are not.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that out of the box - you can't.

You can create your index manually and query it, or use something like [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/) to search for keys based on values. But Redis doesn't support any sort of indexing out of the box.

Comment: @experiment I'm sorry but I don't have enough knowledge to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Redis works on the premise that you know the key for the object that you're trying to query. If you don't, you need to call getAllObjects and then process them programmatically from within your code to find a matching record.

I would advise designing your keys in such a way that it gives you a window into the sort of data the object of that key holds.

TL;DR - Redis does not support reverse lookups